# How can I apply an Authorizer to select routes in my API Gateway Proxy integration

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm deploying an application to AWS Lambda using the serverless framwework. My application is served by a single Lambda which is why I pass through the request path using `{proxy+}`:

```
functions:
  app:
    runtime: go1.x
    handler: bin/lambda
    events:
      - http:
         path: /{proxy+}
         method: any
```

Now, I'd like to use a custom authorizer Lambda to protect a certain portion of my application (think everything `/admin/`). I thought I could just add another event definition that uses the authorizer like this:

```
functions:
  app:
    runtime: go1.x
    handler: bin/lambda
    events:
      - http:
          path: /admin/{proxy+}
          method: any
          authorizer:
            name: authorizer
            resultTtlInSeconds: 0
            identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
      - http:
         path: /{proxy+}
         method: any
```

yet this has no effect at all. If I apply my authorizer to the root level proxy, it will be applied as expected, so the authorizer itself works as expected.

How can I define my routes in such a scenario? Do I need to use different Lambdas or is there something I am missing?

Comment: it might be the `path: /{proxy+}` which overrides the `path: /admin/{proxy+}`. the `/admin/` part of the later endpoint is handled by the `/{proxy+}` path isn't it?

Comment: This seems like a bug. I have the opposite use case - a nested route *doesn't* use an authorizer, but the root proxy resource does, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options that I can think of:

1. If you really want the endpoints the way you wrote, you can use a general endpoint (root endpoint) and inside that handler check if the request is for `/admin` and then redirect or do some other special case for that.
2. Give up on having a root endpoint and use two "normal" endpoints:

```
    functions:
      app:
        runtime: go1.x
        handler: bin/lambda
        events:
          - http:
              path: /admin/{proxy+}
              method: any
              authorizer:
                name: authorizer
                resultTtlInSeconds: 0
                identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
          - http:
             path: /user/{proxy+}
             method: any
```

Comment: I do know the URL scheme is probably not ideal, but this is mostly about putting an existing HTTP app into hibernation on Lambda so it does accrue EC2 costs anymore... I'll probably try doing the redirect which seems like most plausible thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

you should look into https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html

basically (for open api 3.0) you would define a `security` key on your route. the definition of such key is within `components.securitySchemas`

Comment: I have to admit I have a hard time connecting this information with my setup. The authorizer works, yet I don't know how to leverage precedence of route definitions in my `events` definition. Also, I am using serveless framework, which does not use swagger per se.

Comment: @m90 cant help you there...i made the decision long ago to withdraw my dependency on serverless and learn good cloudformation practices! Its been painful, but promotes some autonomy. Sorry the answer didnt help you...i saw a "swagger-like" config and went for it.